# How to mimic C++ "pass array(pointer) by reference" in C?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Sorry for the cryptic title, I've searched for an answer, but couldn't find one. Anyway, I'm trying to pass a char array into a function and modify the pointer inside the array. Here is an example of what I mean in C++:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

void fill(char*& destination, const char* const input, int size)
{
    memcpy(destination, input, size);
    destination += size;
}

void inner(const char* const string1, int size1)
{
    const int size2 = 8;
    char string2[size2] = "World!\n";

    char output[20];
    char* outputWriter = output;

    fill(outputWriter, string1, size1);
    fill(outputWriter, string2, size2);

    printf(output);
}

int main()
{
    inner("Hello ", 6); 
}
```

Which outputs `Hello World!`

And here is my attempt in C:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

void fill(char** const destination, const char* const input, int size)
{
    memcpy(destination, input, size);
    *destination += size;
}

void inner(const char* const string1, int size1)
{
    const int size2 = 8;
    char string2[size2] = "World!\n";

    char output[20];
    char (*outputWriter)[20] = &output;

    fill((char**)outputWriter, string1, size1);
    fill((char**)outputWriter, string2, size2);

    printf(output);
}

int main()
{
    inner("Hello ", 6); 
}
```

Which outputs `_orld!` , and the casting is not very pretty.

What is the correct way to pass such a pointer to an array to a function in order to be able to modify it similar to what the C++ code does?

Comment: `printf(output);` is considered bad style. use `puts(output);`

Comment: In C++, you aren't passing an *array* by reference (C++ has syntax for that.) You are passing a *pointer* by reference. Your title doesn't match the question.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: It is discouraged to use not because of bad style, but potential security risk. It is fairly ok, if the string is **definitively** a string literal.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh `printf(output);` is _not_ the same as `puts(output);` as `puts()` appends `"\n"`.  A closer match would be  `fputs(output, stdout);`

Comment: @Olaf Yes, Presence of a format specifier can blow up things. That is what I meant. Thanks for clarifying sir. :-)

Comment: @chux Yes sir, I _essentially_ ignored the addition of newline. :-)

Comment: You miss a `*` before destination in `memcpy(destination, input, size);`.

Comment: `memcpy(destination, input, size);` --> `memcpy(*destination, input, size);`

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry for the confusion. I've always found arrays and pointers to be pretty much the same thing, but in this case, the compiler complained about pointing a char** to a char[], so I chose the array wording for the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you are after:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

void fill(char** destination, const char* const input, int size)
{
    memcpy(*destination, input, size);
    *destination += size;
}

void inner(const char* const string1, int size1)
{
    const int size2 = 8;
    char string2[size2] = "World!\n";

    char output[20];
    char* ptr = output;

    fill(&ptr, string1, size1);
    fill(&ptr, string2, size2);

    puts(output);
}

int main()
{
    inner("Hello ", 6);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Don't know why I didn't think of this. :)